# Why Session Variable Sending only last row data to another page

Tags: php, variables, session

here the problem is i need to view the whole row data in view details page when the button is clicked but when i click the last row data is sent through session variable and last row is displayed but i need particular row to display fully when the name is selected of the employee. please help me out in this .

thank you

index.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$sql = "SELECT empname,salary,contact_no,department,empdesg FROM add_emp ORDER BY empname ASC ";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
                {
                // output data of each row
                ?>
                <center>
<table cellpadding="20px" cellspacing="40px;" border="2px" align="center" width="device">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
                            <th>Department</th>
                            <th>Designation</th>
                            <th> </th>
                            <?php
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())

                            {
                            $name='';
                            $name=$row["empname"];
                            $department=$row["department"];
                            $designation=$row["empdesg"];
                            ?>
 </tr>
<td>
<?php echo $name?>
</td>

                        <td>
                            <?php echo $department?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $designation?>
                        </td>


                        <td><a href="viewdetails.php">
                            <button>Details</button>
                            </a>
                            <?php

                            $_SESSION['name']= $name;
                            ?>

                        </td>
                        <?php
                        }
                        } 
                        else {
                        echo "0 results";
                        }

                        ?>
```

viewdetails.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
include('connection.php');

$sql="select * from add_emp where empname='$_SESSION[name]'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql); // First parameter is just return of "mysqli_connect()" function
echo "<br>";
echo " <table cellpadding='5px' cellspacing='10px' border='1px' align='center'>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ // Important line !!! Check summary get row on array ..
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" ."Name". "</th>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['empname']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" ."DOB". "</th>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['eage']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" ."Adhaar Number". "</th>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['adhaar']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" ."Address". "</th>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['address']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" ."Salary". "</th>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['salary']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" ."Phone Number". "</th>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['contact_no']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" ."Department". "</th>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['department']. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" ."Designation". "</th>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['empdesg']. "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
             echo "<tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Please EDIT your question and explain clearly and concisely exactly what is "wrong". What are you expecting? What are you getting? What have you tried to solve it with?  Then we can help you `:-)`

Comment: yes sir updated any doubt in that part

Comment: Session var only sends last record because you have this `$_SESSION['name']= $name;` in a `while` loop which assigns the value of $name to $_SESSION['name'] on every pass overwriting itself.

Comment: any other alternative to make it correct

Comment: Anyone can help me out in-this please